# Does the carrier matter when flashing custom roms?

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, lineageos, carriers, lg-g6

I am getting the lg g6 tomorrow and i saw that there was twrp and lineage and a couple others. But xda also has a thread that is specifically tmobile and thats where im getting my phone. but the tmobile thread had 0 developement going on. So will the carrier matter?

Comment: Go get the US open variant - only that and the European variants are officially bootloader unlocked at the moment (AFAIK) and thus only them get any sort of development.

Comment: Im getting it free so i dont really get to pick.

Comment: Also getting the kernel sources you could build your own bootloader and flash it yes? If I remember correctly manufacturers are required to release kernel sources.

Comment: Kernel ≠ bootloader. Without an unlocked bootloader you aren't supposed to flash any 3rd-party stuff.

Comment: So bottom line if i install the special twrp will i be able to flash lineage

Comment: The bottom line to that is you buy the variants with unlocked bootloaders so you'll be able to install TWRP in the first place.

Comment: I ended up getting the j3 anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Most times probably not, but there are some carriers which not only apply software modifications but also obtain specific hardware configurations from manufacturers (AFAIK Verizon is one of those having done that in the past for some devices at least, and T-Mobile was mentioned in that context as well).

Which means, there's no "generic answer" to this question, but you must check for each device separately. If the hardware matches, the carrier should be irrelevant concerning the custom ROM – as the latter then again matches the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Andy Yan is right. The phones sold by all major carriers have their bootloader locked. Your G6 variant won't be the same G6 that allows TWRP (and thus custom roms, and root) to be installed easily.

See Post:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g6/development/recovery-twrp-lg-g6-us997-unofficial-t3629883

Saying :
*A message to those with other variants of the G6:
The H870 International variant and the us997 are the only ones with an official bootloader unlock from LG.*

Comment: Additional info: not even the TW/HK H870DS and the Australian H870 are included - only Europeans get the privilege.